Assigning Cores of your Computer to a Task
I am trying to simulate different combinations of two loop indices in R (I am using Windows).
I think my computer is doing this all at once. For example, suppose I want to list numbers 1 to 10. My computer is listing them 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. I think it would be better if my computer split the load such that one core on my computer listed (1,2,3,4,5) and the second core listed (6,7,8,9,10) ... then everything could be joined together and thus save time.
Here is my simulation I am trying to speed up:
lambda <- 1/5  
n <- 100000  

bus_arrivals <- rexp(n, rate = lambda)

results <- data.frame(
  s = numeric(), 
  t = numeric(), 
  prob_x_greater_than_t = numeric(),   
  prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s = numeric())

for (s in seq(1, 10, by = 1)) {
  for (t in seq(1, 10, by = 1)) {
    # Part 1: 
    p1 <- sum(bus_arrivals > t) / n

    # Part 2:
    waited_s <- bus_arrivals[bus_arrivals > s]
    p2 <- sum(waited_s > s + t) / length(waited_s)

    results <- rbind(
      results, 
      data.frame(
        s = s, 
        t = t, 
        prob_x_greater_than_t = p1,    
        prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s = p2
      )
    )
  }
}

Can someone please show me how I can parallelize this code in R so that cores that are  currently idle can be assigned some of this work? Or in general, is there any way to speed up this code?
Ideally, I want to make the above code run faster so I can change the number of iterations in the loop:
for (s in seq(1, 10, by = 0.01)) {
  for (t in seq(1, 10, by = 0.1)) {


Welcome to SO.  In general, an easy solution to this sort of problem is to convert your for loops to lapplys and then convert the lapplys to mclapplys from the parallel package.  of course, you can always go directly to the mclapplys if you wish.  By the way, as your rbind is inside your loops, that's highly inefficient.

Hey Limey, thanks for the tips. I stayed up all night and tried to figure out how to use these libraries you mentioned ... I just wrote an answer ... does it look correct to you?

If you say the results are correct, I believe you.  As you haven't stated your exact problem, I can't do anything else.
As I mentioned in my original comment, having an rbind inside a loop is very inefficient. See Chapter 2 of The R Inferno.
To start, slightly modify your calc_probs function so that it's self-contained and gives reproducible results.  Rename it calc_probs1:
calc_probs1 <- function(s) {
  set.seed(123)
  lambda <- 1/5  
  n <- 100
  bus_arrivals <- rexp(n, rate = lambda)
  results <- data.frame(s = numeric(), t = numeric(), prob_x_greater_than_t = numeric(), prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s = numeric())
  
  for (t in seq(1, 10, by = 0.01)) {
    # Part 1: 
    p1 <- sum(bus_arrivals > t) / n
    # Part 2:
    waited_s <- bus_arrivals[bus_arrivals > s]
    p2 <- sum(waited_s > s + t) / length(waited_s)
  
    results <- rbind(results, data.frame(s = s, t = t, prob_x_greater_than_t = p1, prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s = p2))
  }
  return(results)
}

Now rewrite is as calc_probs2 and take the rbind out of the loop, replacing it with the dplyr equivalent, bind_rows. bind_rows accepts a list of objects to row bind, and a list is exactly what lapply gives you.
library(dplyr)

calc_probs2 <- function(s) {
  set.seed(123)
  lambda <- 1/5  
  n <- 100
  bus_arrivals <- rexp(n, rate = lambda)
  lapply(
    seq(1, 10, by = 0.01),
    function(t) {
      p1 <- sum(bus_arrivals > t) / n
      waited_s <- bus_arrivals[bus_arrivals > s]
      p2 <- sum(waited_s > s + t) / length(waited_s)
    
      data.frame(
        s = s, 
        t = t, 
        prob_x_greater_than_t = p1, 
        prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s = p2
      )
    }
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows()
}

As a sanity check, make sure the two versions of calc_probs give the same answer.
identical(calc_probs1(5), calc_probs2(5))
[1] TRUE

All good.
Now compare the performance of the two functions using the microbenchmark package.
Simply to save execution time,  reduce n and run each function for only one value of s.  Differences in performance will be multipled in your real use case by about 100 (n) times 1000 (different values of s).
library(microbenchmark)
library(magrittr)

microbenchmark(
  list = list(
    calc_probs1 = calc_probs1(5), 
    calc_probs2 = calc_probs2(5)
  ),
times = 10
)
Unit: nanoseconds
        expr min lq mean median uq max neval
 calc_probs1   7  9 51.3      9  9 435    10
 calc_probs2   9  9 11.6      9  9  34    10

So on my system (which is old and slow), I get a reduction in execution time of just less than 80% by switching from the for loop with an internal rbind to an lapply with an external rbind.
Your results may be different.
You could, of course, refine calc_probs2 even further by replacing its lapply with another call to `%dopar%, but that would require careful management of the number of cores used in each step of the process.  Whether that's a worthwhile complication, you will have to judge.

wow, thank you so much! I was not expecting such a complete answer!

so there was no need to write anything in parallel?

btw if you are interested, here some more context as to why I am doing this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4911063/testing-the-memoryless-property-of-the-exponential-distribution

If you look at the answer I posted to my own question, I tried to take your code and make it into another function so I can run it for different combinations of (s,t) . Did I correctly adapt your code?

You should delete the set.seed call: that’s just for reproducibility. I’d make n and lambda arguments to the function rather than hardcoding them inside it. If the speed gain is sufficient for your needs, there’s no need to parallelise, but you could. SO is not a code review site, so have no comment on the correctness of what you have done.

Here is a solution I tried:
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1

registerDoParallel(cores = no_cores)

lambda <- 1/5  
n <- 100000  
bus_arrivals <- rexp(n, rate = lambda)

# main function
calc_probs <- function(s) {
    results <- data.frame(s = numeric(), t = numeric(), prob_x_greater_than_t = numeric(), prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s = numeric())
    
    for (t in seq(1, 10, by = 0.01)) {
        # Part 1: 
        p1 <- sum(bus_arrivals > t) / n
        
        # Part 2:
        waited_s <- bus_arrivals[bus_arrivals > s]
        p2 <- sum(waited_s > s + t) / length(waited_s)
        
        results <- rbind(results, data.frame(s = s, t = t, prob_x_greater_than_t = p1, prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s = p2))
    }
    
    return(results)
}

# execute in paralel
results <- foreach(s = seq(1, 10, by = 0.01), .combine = rbind) %dopar% calc_probs(s)

I think this is correct? It runs much faster and seems to produce the desired result?
EDIT: Using Limey's answer, I tried to make this modification:
# Limey's answer for different combinations of s and t:

library(dplyr)

calc_probs2 <- function() {
    set.seed(123)
    lambda <- 1/5  
    n <- 100
    bus_arrivals <- rexp(n, rate = lambda)
    
    results <- lapply(
        seq(1, 10, by = 0.01),
        function(s) {
            lapply(
                seq(1, 10, by = 0.01),
                function(t) {
                    p1 <- sum(bus_arrivals > t) / n
                    waited_s <- bus_arrivals[bus_arrivals > s]
                    p2 <- sum(waited_s > s + t) / length(waited_s)
                    
                    data.frame(
                        s = s, 
                        t = t, 
                        prob_x_greater_than_t = p1, 
                        prob_x_greater_than_s_plus_t_given_x_greater_than_s = p2
                    )
                }
            ) %>% 
                bind_rows()
        }
    ) %>% 
        bind_rows()
    
    return(results)
}


# launch function
output = calc_probs2()

